# Understanding Asynchronous Behavior with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I understand that AJAX calls are asynchronous by default, meaning they are initiated and the browser continues executing subsequent code without waiting for the server response. However, I am curious about a specific behaviour in the following scenario:

for example,

```
<script>
$.get("/Home/GetData", function() {
//do something with table
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//create the table
});
</script>
```

Is it **ever** possible for the browser to execute the script containing the ajax request if the ajax request's response is pretty fast than before executing the second script?

Comment: Regarding the question in the last paragraph, the answer is no. Network latency is never low enough to respond in the nanosecond interval between lines of code being executed. You will need to use promises/callbacks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so the code (even though highly unreadable) would work fine 100% of the time?

Comment: No - that would never work, assuming that your expectation is for the AJAX to fetch the data and then the second `script` block would build the table from that fetched data. This is why you need to use a promise or callback.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, wrong assumption. I expect that AJAX is going to be slow, the second script is going to create the table, and then the response from ajax would work on that created table otherwise it will fail (not finding a table).

Comment: Ah I see - then yes that would work, although it's a little risky as you're relying on the DOM responding in time to build the table. Normally this would be fine, but there's still situations where it may not.

Comment: Even if the network latency was null, there would not be any chance of the code to be run before. If you want a better understanding of that, research "event loop javascript" on your favorite search engine

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan "but there's still situations where it may not."
That's why I wanted to confirm the chances being 100%. :)

Comment: There's never a 100% chance of anything - all you can do is mitigate risk

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan What if I added the document.ready function in the second script.

Comment: It would have no effect. The 'safest' approach would be to build the table in the DOM and then make your AJAX request. This guarantees that the DOM will be in the state you require. I assume you've got some other limitations preventing you from doing this, so making the AJAX request first then building the DOM while the AJAX is in flight *should* be ok in most cases, but cannot be guaranteed.